# calculate residuals

Tags: regression, residuals, cointegration

I am stepping through some code trying to understand a cointegration function.

There is one function that has me very confused. y is a 1800 x 2 matrix of difference & x is the same dimension just lagged.

Can anyone explain what this function is doing? Is this just some clever way of calculating residuals?

```
def resid(y, x):
    r = y - np.dot(x, np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(x), y))
    return r
```